# C# adjustable hotkey funtion for press Buttons question

Tags: c#

Im creating a Hotkey funtion atm so users can adjust Keybindings to their own needs, before i set the keys and they were not adjustable. This is what i used before.

```
public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.D:
            // stuff
            Salvagebtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.F12:
            // stuff
            pausebtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.K:
            //stuff
            Geardropbtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.F:
            //stuff
            Gamblebtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.A:
            //stuff
            LeftClickSpambtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.H:
            // stuff
            openGRbtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.B:
            //stuff                    
            gemupbtn.PerformClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now i made a setting Tab where ppl can change Keybindings which looks like this.

[image]

How can i get it going that instead of the "case Keys.D:" it will react to the Keybinding in the Textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do it. One way you could go would be to assign the keybindings to a Dictionary where UserActions is an enum defining the possible action:

```
public enum UserAction
{
    Salvage, Pause, Drop // etc...
}
```

Then when the user presses a key, something like:

```
public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string k = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    if (KeyBindings.Contains(k)) //KeyBindings is your field or variable which is a Dictionary<string, UserAction>
    {
      var action = KeyBindings[k]
      switch (action)
      {
        case UserAction.Salvage:
          // stuff
          Salvagebtn.PerformClick();
          break;
        case UserAction.Pause:
          // stuff
          pausebtn.PerformClick();
          break;
         // and so on...
```

Assigning values to the dictionary:

```
var KeyBindings = new Dictionary<string, UserAction>;
KeyBindings["D"] = UserAction.Salvage;
KeyBindings["A"] = UserAction.Pause;
```

If you need to get a key from the user's input, you can use Enum.TryParse(input):

```
Keys key;
if (Enum.TryParse<Keys>(textBoxSalvage.Text, out key))
{
    KeyBinding[textBoxSalvage.Text] = UserAction.Salvage; // note that 'UserAction.something' comes from the context
}
```

Comment: sry  for  the  late  respond but how would  the Dictionary for Keybindings look like ? i tried alot of but stuff but didnt got it to work yet guess im to new to programming :D

Comment: I'll edit my answer to give you an idea. Please upvote and/or mark s answer if it ends up helping you.